# My Tensorflow generate wired sequence after uploading utf-8 txt file and don't know what part to fix

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, prediction, text-generation, google-generativeai

I just started learning ML development using Tensorflow. I uploaded Steve Jobs' commencement speech at Stanford in 2005, and uploaded the text file in txt to generate a new Steve Jobs's speech by using built in RNN. But my system returned wired sequence of texts and don't know what part to fix.

Since it's a very long codes, I share my GoogleColab page here for you to take a look:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OPfl88B4EyVX-RoQ1xBLi-e-tJAiXjNO?usp=sharing

Please let me know if you find out the reason why it happens.
Thanks!

Jessica

I tried changing text format from 'utf-8' to 'windows-1252'. The codes are running, but the texts are broken.